# Angular Push Messages not showing

Tags: php, angular, laravel, typescript

I'm developing an Angular App which should receive a Push Notification from a server (Laravel with Webpush) and then show it as a notification. For this, i'm using Angular Service Worker.

Currently, i can test the Push Notification with the Application debug tab of chrome, and the Notification Shows as it should. However, when i try to push the notification from server, the app receives it, but doesn't shows anything. As a workaround, i created the notification directly via the Notification API of browser, and it shows. However, this doesn't work when the app is not opened.

Currently, this is my TS in my Push Service.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { RestService } from "./rest.service";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { SwPush } from '@angular/service-worker';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class PushService {
  readonly VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY = VAPID_KEY

  constructor(
    private restservice: RestService,
    private authservice: AuthService,
    private swPush:SwPush
  ) {
    if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
      this.initNotifications();

      /*This is the part where i test the message reception from the server, in order to make it work i 
        use the Browser Notification API and it shows as it should. However, it doesn't fire the 
       notification if i dont use the "New Notification" and with this approach, the service worker won't 
       work*/

      this.swPush.messages.subscribe((message:any)=>{
        var notification = new Notification(message.title,{
          body:message.body
        })
      })
    }
  }

  initNotifications() {

        this.swPush.requestSubscription({
          serverPublicKey: this.VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY
      }).then(sub => this.storePushSubscription(sub))

  }


  storePushSubscription(pushSubscription) {


    let subscriptionData:any = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pushSubscription)));
    subscriptionData.user_id = this.authservice.loggedUser.user_id;

    console.log(subscriptionData);

    this.restservice.post(subscriptionData, "push")
  }

}
```

And this is the Code in Laravel which sends the notification in the ToWebPush Method;

class Push extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

```
protected $notificactionObject;

public function __construct($notificactionObject) {
    $this->notificactionObject = $notificactionObject;
}

public function via($notifiable)
{
    return [WebPushChannel::class];
}

public function toWebPush($notifiable, $notification)
{
    return (new WebPushMessage)
    ->title($this->notificactionObject->title)
    ->body("Body Text");
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Just solved it.

The problem was the way Laravel was sending the Notification JSON. I believe the format was changed and the library didn't updated. In fact, i had the same issue when testing with an Express backend. The correct syntax must be something like this.

```
{
notification: {
    "body" : "Lorem Ipsum",
    "title" : "Lorem Ipsum",
    "icon" : "Icon URL",
  }}
```

However, the webpush library (And in some tutorials) show the Notification syntax as following (Without the initial notification tag)

```
{
    "body" : "Lorem Ipsum",
    "title" : "Lorem Ipsum",
    "icon" : "Icon URL"
}
```

In order to solve this in Laravel, i had to create a new Class which would have a notification property of type WebpushMessage. So the Complete Notification code is the following

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use NotificationChannels\WebPush\WebPushMessage;
use NotificationChannels\WebPush\WebPushChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;


class Push extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $notificactionObject;

    public function __construct($notificactionObject) {
        $this->notificactionObject = $notificactionObject;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [WebPushChannel::class];
    }

    public function toWebPush($notifiable, $notification)
    {

        $wpm = (new WebPushMessage)
        ->title($this->notificactionObject->title)
        ->body(strip_tags($this->notificactionObject->description_html))
        ->icon('https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/notification-flat.png');

        $rwpm = (new RealWebPushMessage)->notification($wpm);

        return $rwpm;
    }

}



class RealWebPushMessage
{
    /**
     * @var WebPushMessage
     */
    protected $notification;
    protected $options = [];

    public function notification(WebPushMessage $wpm)
    {
        $this->notification = $wpm;
        return $this;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        $cArray = $this;
        $cArray->notification = $cArray->notification->toArray();
        return Arr::except(array_filter(get_object_vars($cArray)), ['options']);
    }

    public function getOptions()
    {
        return $this->options;
    }
}
```