# How can I implement push notifications in my Angular web application?

Tags: angular

As part of the web application , I am asked to send push notification on top of the screen. Just like we have for Windows Update. Similarly I want Pop up notification of the browser in case of any event. Please can someone help how the same can be done. My application is Angular based.
Example: In Whats App web, if we allow the notification in Chrome. any message will be displayed as a popup notification. How this can be achieved?

Not able to find how this can be achieved? are there any plugins?

Comment: does this help you ? 
https://www.devstringx.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Push Messages not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60161940/angular-push-messages-not-showing)